# Identify the failure of a executeBatch() in JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, batch-updates

I am using the following code to Insert data into a table.

```
test_conn.setAutoCommit(false);
stmt = test_conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO ...");

while(RSet.next()){
   for(int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++){
       stmt.setString(i, RSet.getString(i));
   }
   stmt.addBatch();
}

stmt.executeBatch();
test_conn.commit();
```

other processing methods to occur only all the above rows are successfully inserted....

when I Insert into table using `executeBatch()`, if an SQL Exception or Error occurs in Inserting , is it possible to find Insertion of which Record has thrown the exception?

Answer (score 0):

You have to `try-catch` the `stmt.executeBatch()` call and check for details in the exception. Batch execution will stop on first error that will occure.

Comment: Yea. I know it will stop when batch fails. I want to know, how to get the Record which failed.

Comment: I think you cannot - the only thing is to hope that exceptin will have some guidence info from the RDBMS. Its like you would execute multiple SQLs separated with;. In case of error, it will not show you which statement failed.

Comment: @codeFreak `stmt.executeBatch();` will return an integer array containing the insert status of each record. For i'th element, value `-3` indicates an `ERROR`, `>=0` indicates `OK` status. You can keep a separate array for maintaining the insert statements (`stmt.toString()`) and then compare with the result array to find the insert query which failed.

Comment: @ArjunSK, could you give the source of this answer please? Does the error scenario when an element is -3 also applies when we run exexuteBatch for update queries?

Comment: @AkilaAmarasinghe int array values explanation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48921660/what-does-return-value-3-indicate-when-sending-a-jdbc-bulk-insert-to-crate-io

Answer (score 0):

If exception is thrown and you want to know what exactly was the exception for every failed insert you could use this catch block and it will print exact reason for failing:

```
  catch (SQLException sqlException) {
        while (sqlException != null) {
            System.err.println("Error msg: " + sqlException.getMessage());
            sqlException = sqlException.getNextException();
        }
    }
```

This will print on console something like this: "...Exception in record #123..." which shows in what record did exception occurred and will print SQLCODE and SQLSTATE